# If an event fires and nobody is listening, does it make a sound?

Tags: .net, events, event-handling

I was just wondering how exactly the .Net framework handles events.

Presumably when an event fires, all registered handlers are called (on new threads?). If there are no handlers attached, how far does the event handling get? Is there an internal "There are no listeners" flag to prevent wasted cycles?

The question comes as I was pondering the huge number of unused events generated by complex forms (especially WPF). All the mouse entering/exiting/etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events don't work like that.

As far as the CLR is concerned, an event is just a pair of methods named `add_EventName` and `remove_EventName`.  (these are called accessors, just like properties)

How to implement these methods and invoke the handlers is up to the implementing classes.

Typically, events are implemented by storing all handlers for each event in a multicast delegate (either in a compiler-generated backing field from an implicit event, or in something like `EventHandlerList`).

Invoking a multicast delegate will run each method synchronously, in insertion order.
If there are no methods, it will be null.  (there is no such thing as an empty multicast delegate instance)

Comment: +1. And to answer one of the questions posed more directly - when no one's subscribed to an event, it's value is `null`, so a check must be performed or else a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown. So yes, there is a flag that says "there are no listeners", which is `this.MyEvent == null`.

Answer (score 1):

Events are implemented with a multicast delegate, which is `null` when there are no handlers associated with it. In the CLR code that responds to the event, you'll see something like this:

```
void OnEventName(EventNameArgs e)
{
    // Only invoke the delegate if there are handlers associated with it
    if (EventNameDelegate != null)
    {
        EventNameDelegate(sender, e);
    }
}
```

See [How to: Implement Events in Your Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for examples. This is how events are typically implemented in .NET, including in the library code.